# Manejo de Threads en un DataGridView en VB .net

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, hilos

Estoy actualizando automáticamente y manualmente un datagridview con datos cada cierto tiempo. Para esto, borro todas las filas y las inserto de nuevo manualmente con datos programados. No uso ninguna base de datos ni tabla.

El problema es que estoy con un thread para no bloquear la GUI, y desde ese thread estoy borrando y añadiendo las filas. Sin embargo, después de varias pasadas, el sistema me tira "NullReferenceException".

Éste es mi código:

```
     Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
                Dim wreturnCode1 As Integer = System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf RepeatAction), cancellation.Token)
        End Sub

        Private Sub RepeatAction(ByVal obj As Object)
            Dim token As System.Threading.CancellationToken = CType(obj, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
            FormTimer.Enabled = True
            AddHandler FormTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf AutoTaskRepo
       End Sub

       Private Async Sub AutoTaskRepo()
        FormTimer.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        FormTimer.Enabled = True

   End Sub
```

Éste es el error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' en
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Información adicional: Referencia a objeto no establecida como
>   instancia de un objeto.

¿Algúna solución?
No puedo avanzar con esto.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con este código:

```
DataGridView1.update()
DataGridView1.refresh()
```

Después de hacer cualquier modificación al `grid`.

En algún punto el `grid` se queda sin los `rows` estas intentando acceder, o algo así, lo mejor será ir actualizándolo después de cada acción.